# Use in formula text from other cell

Tags: google-sheets

Maybe someone here can help me. A1 contains a string that should be used in B2. This is the whole formula:

```
=sum(filter('foobar'!$B$4:$B;Month('foobar'!$A$4:$A)=(D1)))
```

This should be in A1

```
'foobar'!$B$4:$B;Month('foobar'!$A$4:$A)
```

This should be in B2

```
=sum(filter( ? =(D1)))
```

What goes into the place of the questionmark? I tried several options, like &, concentate, indirect.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible, unfortunately. You cannot use a Sheets spreadsheet formula to "evaluate" a string like that. The best you can do is to use INDIRECT, but that function only supports cell/range references, nothing else. So:

```
A1:  'foobar'!$B$4:$B
A2:  'foobar'!$A$4:$A

B2:  =SUM(FILTER(INDIRECT(A1);MONTH(INDIRECT(A2))=D1))
```

---

Alternatively, with [QUERY](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1388882):

```
A1:  'foobar'!$A$4:$B
A2:  ="select B where month(A) = "&(D1-1)

B2:  =SUM(QUERY(INDIRECT(A1);A2;0))
```